# Finding directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One of the tough ones..

Find a directional derivative of $f=x^2+y^2$ in the direction of $\vec{a}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}$ (vector symbols should be above the letters) at the point $(1,2)$

any ideas?

Comment: Removed the [tag:complex-analysis] tag. Being difficult to some does not mean it is complex anaylsis.

Answer (score 2):

The directional derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$ is
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\bigg( f(\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})\bigg).$$
Plug, chug, repeat.

**Edit**: Plug in $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{i}-\mathbf{j} = (1,-1)$. So, for example, $$f(\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{v}) = f\big( (1,2) + t(1,-1) \big) = f(1 + t, 2-t).$$
Hopefully this will get the ball rolling.

Comment: still too complex -.-

Comment: mokoto (kusanagi??), be more specific. Do you know what $f({\bf x}+t{\bf v})$ means? Do you know what it means to plug something into an expression? Here, $t{\bf v}=(t,-t)$ and ${\bf x}=(1,2)$ so $f({\bf x}+t{\bf v})=f(1+t,2-t)=(1+t)^2+(2-t)^2$. Can you continue? Do you know how to take the derivative of a function of one variable?

Comment: Yes, i got this now Thanks! :)

Comment: Should $\mathbf v$ be normalized?

Comment: Yes it should be the unit vector along the direction of $(1, -1)$

Answer (score 0):

Directional Derivative = $\nabla f .\hat a $  So calculate the $\nabla f$ at the given point and take the dot product of it with the unit vector along $\vec a$.